# How can I center my google maps info window content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, google-maps-api-3

I have this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uzyjjj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) here that opens a google maps info window.
I've removed(hidden) the close button, but the window is still off on the right side padding and/or margins.

How can I center the bootstrap card that sites in the info window?

Comment: The card info window seems to be at the center. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: If you look, there is more white space on the right than the left.

Comment: If you mean the white space inside the card, that is because it has `max-width: 375px; width: calc(100% - 10px);` in its style. There is extra space in the card because the text isn't long enough to wrap. If you shrink the width if your browser below 375px, the whitespace will go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That additional white space on the right side is added by the following style:

```
<div class="gm-style-iw-d" style="overflow: scroll; max-height: 508px;">
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

which means that browser always display scrollbars whether or not any content is actually clipped.
Scrollbar is not visible for user here since it is hardly customized with google maps.

You should change it to `overflow: auto`:

```
:host ::ng-deep .gm-style-iw-d {
  overflow: auto !important;
}
```

Another issue is located here:

```
<div class="gm-style-iw gm-style-iw-c" style="padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

As you can see paddings are removed for right side. You should keep them as they were before (`12px`):

```
:host ::ng-deep .gm-style-iw-c {
    padding-right: 12px !important;
    padding-bottom: 12px !important;
}
```

And the last piece of the solution is to remove hardcoded width from your cards:

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                         remove this
```

so that cards will have width 100% as by default.

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-greodt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)**

[image]

Comment: Hi yurzui. Thank you so much this helps. Quick question - what does "::ng-deep" mean?

Comment: `::ng-deep` combinator tells Angular to apply style to the current component and all its descendants. Without it style would be applied only to the HTML in the component's own template. See also https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Comment: in your link it says it's deprecated, should I use :host >>> .class instead?

Comment: It says that you should use `::ng-deep` From the docs `As such we plan to drop support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep). Until then ::ng-deep should be preferred for a broader compatibility with the tools.`

Comment: Hi yurzui. I just noticed that when you remove the "width: 18rem;" the card doesn't flex when you minimize the screen. So if the screen in small it will chop off the right side content. Is there a way to keep a min width of the content or make it flex?

Comment: Try replacing `width: 19.2rem !important;` with `max-width: 19.2rem !important;` I updated the demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-greodt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css